# Node express routes and app.js

Tags: node.js, express

Ok, so I am learning nodejs and express. I am thinking that app.js is kinda like the controller, in which all my functions go. So I added the following in the index.js file under routes:

```
/*GET test cases */
router.get('/testcase/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.render('testcase', { title: 'Zephyr Report - Test Case', testCaseId: req.params.id  });
});
```

So I assume I would not right other variables and code here to pass in. So looking at other posts I am confused on how to how to write more code for this route. Also where should I put this in the app js file. Should these functions be above or below the following two lines:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

Would I do something like this?

```
app.get('/testcase/:id', routes.testcase, function(req, res)) {
    // Code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to put all of your controller logic into one file.  To spread your logic around you can require another file at the top of your index.js like

```
tests = require('../controllers/tests_controller')
```

Then you can use functions that you export in the tests_controller

```
app.get('/tests/:id', tests.show);
```

You just have to export the show function in your controller

```
module.exports = {
   show: show
}
```